# Getting Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Match error: Failed Match.Where validation in field username in field user.username

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

I'm trying to create the simplest custom authentication possible in a meteor app (not using the accounts-ui package basically). But running into a lot of problems.

I have a form that creates a user just fine. But when I attempt to run

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(...)
```

I get the following error:

`Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Match error: Failed Match.Where validation in field username in field user.username`

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're using some kind of auto-form. In theory all you have is your form:

```
<template name="loginform">
  <input type="text" id="username"/>
  <input type="password" id="password"/>
  <button id="login-button">Login</button>
</template>
```

and then an event like this:

```
Template.loginform.events({
  'click #login-button': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.loginWithPassword($('#username').val(), $('#password').val(), function(err) {
        if (err){
            // login failed
        }
        else {
            // login successful
            Router.go('/targetEndpoint'); // example: redirect to different view (if you have a router)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It was the auto-form that was causing the problem. Is there any docs on this?

Comment: Really depends on the auto-form package/implementation you're using.

Comment: I didn't add any, are there some enabled by default? Only packages are accounts-ui, jquery so far. Thanks again on this!

Comment: If you want to write the login logic yourself, I wouldn't use `accounts-ui`

Comment: Just curious, why cannot we use Accounts.onLogin on server side when using Meteor.loginwithPassword ?

Comment: I am not using Blaze or AutoForms, but got the problem today as well. What might be causing this?